# SVG support on Android, current status

Tags: android, browser, svg

Does Android support SVG (natively)?

I found old answers here or on the web, but I don't understand the **current** situation.

Please give a reference if possibile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does Android support SVG (natively)?

That depends on what you mean by "Android", "SVG", and "natively".

Android is a mobile operating system. It has multiple versions.

SVG is a standard. It has multiple versions.

"Natively" could mean anything from "I can decode SVG through some Java classes" to "the stock Android Web browser can render SVG".

I can tell you that the stock Android Web browser renders [this Web page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectMiniApproved/animate-dom-01-f.html) fine on Android 3.2 and Android 4.0, but fails on Android 2.3.

I can tell you that there is no SVG parser set of Java classes, and that `ImageView` and similar widgets have no ability to work with SVG directly. You may be able to use `WebView` to display some `SVG`, given that the stock browser seems to support it on newer Android versions, though it's conceivable that the SVG support is via some plugin that is not automatically available to `WebView`.

I cannot tell you what version of SVG is supported by the browser, as that does not appear to be documented. You would need to run some tests and see if it supports the particular SVG structures that you wish to use.

Comment: I meant "Android Web browser", but you answered to more than that. Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any plugins or library projects which can render svg in webview on 2.x ??

Comment: @droidhot: None that I am aware of, though I have not gone looking. There are SVG libraries for Android Java-based apps, such as `svg-android`.

Comment: @CommonsWare svg-android converts svg to canvas which disables svg functionality i hope so and its not sor svg stream but raw svg files thanx for your prompt replay i had seen an sdk tinyline but there demo app is not working -- i hope to find some library thanx again

Answer (score 7):

http://caniuse.com/#search=svg The android browser column shows the android version whose default browser will have SVG support. All versions 3.0 and above have basic SVG support.

You can see a comprehensive advanced feature breakdown on the same page.